# jQuery animation for an unknown number of <li>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this code is super lame but it was working very well 'till now so I kept it. 
But now I have too many < li >'s and I can't add them manually in the js because it's on wordpress and it depends on the category page so the number of < li >'s changes every time.

My question is; **how can I keep that animation and make it work with an undefined number of < li >'s without having to add them manually? And is there a way to stop the scroll bar scrolling-away without using the css overflow-y: hidden ?!**

HERE'S THE DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/NdRDh/

Thank you very much! Hope you can help me!!

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('li').each(
            function(i) {
                $(this)
                    .delay(400)
                    .animate(
                        {
                            'top' : '10px'
                        }, 1500 + (500*i));
            });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NdRDh/10/).

Oh, and please note that you're repeating the same `id` for *all* of your `li` elements: this is invalid HTML, as:

> `id` = **name [CS]**
>
> > This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

<sub>(Quoted from: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)</sub>

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: thank you very much this works great! I didn't know that about the id, thank you will change it!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(400).animate({'top': '10px'}, (500*i)+1000);
});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NdRDh/6/

as a sidenote you cannot have multiple elements with the same id

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()`, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/NdRDh/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have id and class swapped: give them 'common' as the class and their class names as id's and then you can select them all and call animate with:

```
 $('li.common').animate(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(400).animate({'top' : '10px'}), 1000 + 500 * index);
});
```